# How can i check the array has object or not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

i want to check if the old array has object or not if the old array has the object it should show me the button if the oldArray has zero object the button should be hidden  the code is given below  thanks...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    GET_DEFAULTS
    NSMutableArray *array = [defaults objectForKey:kShouldResume];

    NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [defaults objectForKey:kShouldResume];
    if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil)
    {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil)
        {
            array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
            if ([oldSavedArray containsObject])
            {
                btnResumeGame.hidden=NO;
            }
            else
            {
                btnResumeGame.hidden=YES;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use count property of your NSMutablearray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

```
    if ( [oldSavedArray count]>0 ){

         btnResumeGame.hidden=NO;
    }
    else{
        btnResumeGame.hidden=YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Array has property count.
You can check weather count is zero or more than that as you require..
like

```
oldSavedArray.count
```